# Process videos without any external API

Tags: java, swing, video, graphics, bufferedimage

How to process videos in Java without any external API?

I have a mpeg4 or mpeg2 video which I want to view in a `JPanel` reading each frame one after another and then displaying the frames with `paintComponent()`. Displaying each file as `BufferedImage` in `Graphics g`.

My question is how to get an array of `BufferedImage` class from the video files?

Comment: *"..process videos without any external API"*   Write an API of your own.  Note that is my way of saying - by the time you have functional code for doing so, it will *be* an API.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Decoding i-frames from mpeg1 is not that difficult (they're standard JPEG images). B-frames and p-frames are progressively harder to decode (good luck with d-frames). Mpeg2 and Mpeg4 are orders of magnitude harder to decode then mpeg1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* process videos in Java without relying on external libraries. It will take a fair amount of coding effort on your part, so be forewarned.

If you're decoding an MPEG-2 file, that will probably be a program stream, so you'll need to write the code to take that apart. MPEG-4 part 2 video will probably arrive in an MP4 container which will require a lot of code to take apart (not too hard, just a lot of details). So this is just the container; inside will be chunks of compressed video and audio.

Now you will need to decode either the MPEG-2 or MPEG-4 video. This will entail parsing variable length codes from the bitstream and recovering syntax elements. For intraframes, this will give you reconstruction data to apply to a stream of macroblocks. You will combine things like DCT coefficients, differential coding, dequantization factors, zigzag scan patterns, discrete cosine transforms, and possibly post-processing filters in order to recover the original image. That's just for intraframes; then there are the interframes which also apply motion vectors and copy data from previously decoded frames.

After getting a frame, you will find that it is in a YUV colorspace. You will probably need to manually convert it to an RGB colorspace in order to plot it onto a BufferedImage.

It's **entirely possible** that you could implement all of this on your own. **Or** you could find an **appropriate Java-friendly multimedia library**, complete with its own API, to do the heavy lifting for you.